# Redirecting on same url result too many redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I have to redirect to same URL, based on some condition, after performing some operation.

My view looks like

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TestAction", "Home")">Text</a>
```

and controller action is as below

```
public ActionResult TestAction()
{
    SomeOperation();
    if(someCondition)
        return Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    else
        return Redirect(otherUrl);
}
```

This is not actual code but POC to keep things simple.

When I click on the link `TestAction` is called continuously and I end up with the message

> website.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: what is the someCondition that you are validating through ? You have redirect to `Request.Url.ToString()` that is probably causing the issue. What happens when you replace it with another URL ?

Comment: Use the overload which says the redirect is temporary, otherwise the browser might cache it and just immediately follow it. ie. `Redirect(..., false);`

Comment: However, if `TestAction` is actually called each time, **what did you expect to happen**? Does `someCondition` allow it to actually escape the redirect loop?

Comment: @maembe I am expecting the same page to load

Comment: @MohamedSahbi I am expecting same page to load. Condition is, if languageReuested is English then stay there only

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There is  no such overload, do I need to import anything?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am not expecting it to be called again and again. It should be called only after I click the link.

Comment: @Imad the method `TestAction` is not being called by any other method when loading the page? You have a loop somewhere in the code.

Comment: But why didn't you expect it to be called again and again? You redirected back to the same URL? Surely that would lead to it being called again? Let's be more specific. You have a url that looks something like `https://yourserver.com/controller/TestAction`. When processing this URL, you redirect to `https://yourserver.com/controller/TestAction`, why did you **not** expect this to keep going?

Comment: @MohamedSahbi I am sure that it is called by clinking on link only. I have created fresh project to reproduce this

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen got your point. Actually when the view is loaded into the browser, url is some thing like `https://yourserver.com/Home/Index` and I want the same URL to be loaded. I understand I got it wrong when I wrote `Request.Url.ToString()`. Is there any way to call previous URL or I have to hardcode it?

Comment: @Imad check LasseV.karlsen's comment. Also, I asked you before **What happens when you replace it with another URL ?** . the Request.Url.ToString() is the issue if the method is not referenced by any other method or link.

Comment: @MohamedSahbi got it. thanks a lot for helping out

Comment: You don't have access to the browser history in your server-side code. You might have it on the client-side, so you might pass on a parameter. I recommend **not** passing the full URL to the previous site, however, to avoid using your site as a vector for "validating" an attack on 3rd party users. ie. I see a link that points to your site, but it actually contains a "redirect" url that points to a malicious 3rd party site. Better to pass a parameter that for your application means "the store page" or "the start page", instead of the full url.